# How to remove millisecond in time value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to remove millisecond in time value and this is my code now to display that time :

```
 foreach (DataRow pRow in dtDaily.Rows)
 {
    double totalst = scndtotalwh + 1800;
    if (totalst > sctime)
    {
       double totalov = totalst - sctime;
       double scot = totalov / 3600;
       TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(scot);
       pRow["OVERTIME"] = t;                                   
     }
 }
```

But, that's code show millisecond and show like this : `00:00:00.2040000` is it possible to remove millisecond?

Comment: 1800 and 3600 look a lot like 30minutes and 1 hour, expressed in seconds. But that would mean that `scot` is in hours. Why pass it to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`?

Comment: YOu mix up the DateTime(point in time) with the FORMATTING in output. I closed this - it is double to another question that explains how to set the formatting in a datarow.

Comment: Also, you can use `double scot = Math.Round(totalov/3600)`.

Comment: @TomTom - Are you sure? First, he's definitely working with durations, aka `TimeSpan`s, not points in time. Secondly, he's setting the timespan directly in the `DataRow`, not converting it into string. Thirdly, it's not clear if he just wants to remove the milliseconds in output, or the data itself.

Comment: Does not matter. TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(scot); has no milliseconds because it is FULL SECONDS ONLY, so if you see them it is because of the formatstring applied to the output. And ALL examples I find on DataRow point to DataRow not supporting formatting. So, either you set a string, OR you format on the output (i.e. where you SHOW the value).